# tensorflow 2 - how to directly update elements in tf.Variable X at indices?

Tags: tensorflow2.0

Is there a way to directly update the elements in `tf.Variable` X at indices without creating a new tensor having the same shape as X?

[tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensor_scatter_nd_update) create a new tensor hence it appears not updateing the original tf.Variable.

> This operation creates a new tensor by applying sparse updates to the input tensor.

[tf.Variable assign](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable#assign) apparently needs a new tensor `value` which has the same shape of X to update the tf.Variable X.

```
assign(
    value, use_locking=False, name=None, read_value=True
)
```

> value A Tensor. The new value for this variable.

Comment: what do you mean by updating the variable without a new tensor? Isn't this new tensor supposed to be provided?

Comment: @M.Innat, for numpy, it is possible to in-place update. a = np.array([1,2,3]) and a[1] = 0 will directly update the memory allocated to a without creating another numpy array. I believe b = tf.Variable([1,2,3]) and b[1] = 0 is not possible. Then how can I update the memory allocated to b directly without creating another Tensor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the [`tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensor_scatter_nd_update), you're right that it returns a new [**tf.tensor**](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tensor) (and not [**tf.Variable**](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/variable)). But about the [`assign`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable#assign) which is an attribute of [**tf.Variable**](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/variable), I think you somewhat misread the document; the `value` is just the new item that you want to assign in particular indices of your old variable.

AFAIK, in [tensorflow](/questions/tagged/tensorflow) all tensors are immutable like [python](/questions/tagged/python) numbers and strings; you can never update the contents of a tensor, only create a new one, [source](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tensor). And directly updating or manipulating of `tf.tensor` or `tf.Variable` such as [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) like item assignment is still not supported. Check the following Github issues to follow up the discussions: [#33131](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33131), [#14132](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14132).

---

In [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy), we can do an in-place item assignment that you showed in the comment box.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3])  
print(a) # [1 2 3]
a[1] = 0
print(a) # [1 0 3]
```

A similar result can be achieved in **tf.Variable** with `assign` attribute.

```
import tensorflow as tf 

b = tf.Variable([1,2,3])
b.numpy() # array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int32)

b[1].assign(0)
b.numpy() # array([1, 0, 3], dtype=int32)
```

Later, we can convert it to **tf. tensor** as follows.

```
b_ten = tf.convert_to_tensor(b)
b_ten.numpy() # array([1, 0, 3], dtype=int32)
```

We can do such item assignment in **tf.tensor** too but we need to convert it to **tf.Variable** first, (I know, not very intuitive).

```
tensor = [[1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1]]    # tf.rank(tensor) == 2
indices = [[0, 1], [2, 0]]           # num_updates == 2, index_depth == 2
updates = [5, 10]                    # num_updates == 2
x = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(tensor, indices, updates)
x
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 2), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[ 1,  5],
       [ 1,  1],
       [10,  1]], dtype=int32)>
```

```
x = tf.Variable(x)
x
<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(3, 2) dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[ 1,  5],
       [ 1,  1],
       [10,  1]], dtype=int32)>

x[0].assign([5,1])
x
<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(3, 2) dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[ 5,  1],
       [ 1,  1],
       [10,  1]], dtype=int32)>
```

```
x = tf.convert_to_tensor(x)
x
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 2), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[ 5,  1],
       [ 1,  1],
       [10,  1]], dtype=int32)>
```